# Downloading csv file from server

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

I have a system in which frontend is in javascript/ajax and the backend is written using REST(jersey).

I want to download a file using my system. I have searched various forums and implemented the REST web method as follows :

```
@POST
@Produces({"text/csv"})
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Path("getcsv")
public Response  getcsv(
        @FormParam("usernamecsv") String userid,
        @FormParam("filename") String filename
        )
{
    final File fobj = new File("c:/" +userid + "/output/" + filename);
    try
    {
        final FileInputStream f =  new FileInputStream(fobj);
ContentDisposition cd =  
        ContentDisposition.type("file").fileName(fobj.toString()).build(); 
Response response = Response
.ok()
.lastModified(new Date(fobj.lastModified()))
.type("application/octet-stream")
.header("Content-Disposition", cd)
.entity(f)
.build();
return response;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e1)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
```

}

Initially I had used the StreamingOutput class and implemented the write method for it. In that method I had returned the string read from the file. But I have found no difference between that and the above implementation. Both return the string inside the file.

In my frontend this is what I have done

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fun1()
{
$.ajax({
    url: '/RestWSGS/jersey/UserAuthentication/getcsv',
    async: false,
    data: $('#form2').serialize(),
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    processData: false,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data)
     {
        var iframe;
        iframe = document.getElementById("hiddenDownloader");
        if (iframe === null)
        {
            var iframe;
            iframe = document.getElementById("hiddenDownloader");
            if (iframe === null)
            {
                iframe = document.createElement('iframe');  
                iframe.id = "hiddenDownloader";
                //iframe.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                $("#mydiv").append(iframe);
            }
            iframe.src = "http:\\localhost:8080\\c:\abc@abc.com#26 8 2012 13 5 49/gr1/output/test.csv";  
//iframe.src = data; 

        }

        alert('Hi');

     }
 });
}
$(function()
        {
            $(document).delegate("#mydiv","click",function(ev)
            {
            fun1();

            });
        });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv" style='position:absolute;width:20px;height:20px;background:black'></div>
<form id="form2" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
 <input id ="usernamecsv" name="usernamecsv" type="hidden"  value="abc@abc.com#26 8 2012 13 5 49/gr1"/>
  <input id ="filename" name="filename" type="hidden"  value="test.csv" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that I am getting a file not found response( though the data variable has the content of the file), if I assign the iframe.src with the data variable

If I give the uri of the webservice (which I have given to the ajax call) to the iframe.src, I dont know how I will send the parameters.

I really need to show a download prompt to the user and allow him to save the file to the local filesystem. I dont think my REST is right either as it should show a file object in firebug during POST not the contents of the file!

I can just return the string and populate any textarea/ div with it and then ask the user to copy paste it to his file! but that does not look smooth or elegant!

Please help,
Kavita

EDIT:
Tried changing @Produces and type in Response.type() to "application/csv" as well as "application/something" but it always tries to append the contents of the file returned by the server to the current url and opens a search as file is obviously not found!!!

EDIT:
I tried converting POST to GET in the REST and used the data returned. Then it returns a DOCUMENT but still cannot open the file

Comment: If you hit the resource through the browser do you get the file?

Comment: What gives contentType: "text/csv", ?

Comment: @roasted The `@Produces({"text/csv"})` annotation will do.

Comment: the post if viewed thru firebug shows the content of the csv returned.

Comment: @BanksySan means call the webservice??

Comment: anyone can answer this question??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of RnD I think I have found the solution to my problem. This might not be the ideal solution and please let me know if there are any major problems with it.

Basically I tried accessing my file on the server and could only access it from the docroot folder (PATH = C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\docroot). So I realized that I must copy my file from wherever on the server to this location. I did that in the Web service. I read somewhere and was trying to send the file itself from the web service. That was wrong after this change I only sent back a plain text with the path relative to docroot.

Then there was another setback as my file had to be within a folder and the folder name contained a # character. It seems # is not allowed and the iframe just wouldn't ask me for the downloading!!

Now I have modified my code as follows :
REST:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Path("getcsv")
public String  getcsv(
        @FormParam("usernamecsv") String userid,
        @FormParam("filename") String filename
        )
{
    System.out.println("1 = " + getClass().getResource("/" +getClass().getName().substring(
            0, getClass().getName().indexOf("."))).getPath());
    System.out.println("2 = " + getClass().getResource("/" +getClass().getName().substring(
            0, getClass().getName().indexOf("."))).getPath() + "../../../../../docroot/" + userid + "/" + filename);
    final File fobj = new File("c:/" +userid + "/output/" + filename);
    try
    {
        final FileInputStream f =  new FileInputStream(fobj);
    int content;
         ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try
        {
            while ((content = f.read()) != -1) 
            {
                //b[j] = 0;
                // convert to byte
                b.write(content);
            }

        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally 
        {
            try 
            {
                if (f != null)
                    f.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) 
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        File f1 =  new File( getClass().getResource("/"+getClass().getName().substring(
                0, getClass().getName().indexOf("."))).getPath() + "../../../../../docroot/" + userid.substring(0,userid.indexOf("#")) + "/" );
        f1.mkdirs();
        try
        {
        boolean f2 = new File(getClass().getResource("/" +getClass().getName().substring(
                0, getClass().getName().indexOf("."))).getPath() + "../../../../../docroot/" +  userid.substring(0,userid.indexOf("#")) + "/" + filename).createNewFile();
        System.out.println(f2);

        }
        catch (IOException e2)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(getClass().getResource("/" +getClass().getName().substring(
            0, getClass().getName().indexOf("."))).getPath() + "../../../../../docroot/" +  userid.substring(0,userid.indexOf("#")) + "/" + filename));
    try
    {
        fout.write(b.toByteArray());
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        try
        {
            fout.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try
    {
        fout.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
    catch (FileNotFoundException e1)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "/" +  userid.substring(0,userid.indexOf("#")) + "/" + filename;
```

My clientside code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fun1()
{
$.ajax({
    url: '/RestWSGS/jersey/UserAuthentication/getcsv',
    async: false,
    data: $('#form2').serialize(),
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    processData: false,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data)
     {
        var iframe;
        iframe = document.getElementById("hiddenDownloader");
        if (iframe === null)
        {
            var iframe;
            iframe = document.getElementById("hiddenDownloader");
            if (iframe === null)
            {
                iframe = document.createElement('iframe');  
                iframe.id = "hiddenDownloader";
                //iframe.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                $("#mydiv").append(iframe);
            }


        }
        iframe.src = data;  
        alert('Hi');

     }
 });
}
$(function()
        {
    $(document).delegate("#hiddenDownloader","onload",function(ev)
            {
        alert('in onload');
            });

            $(document).delegate("#mydiv","click",function(ev)
            {
            fun1();

    });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<a id ='myhref'  href=""></a>
<div id="mydiv" style='position:absolute;width:20px;height:20px;background:black'></div>
<form id="form2" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
 <input id ="usernamecsv" name="usernamecsv" type="hidden"  value="abc@abc.com#26 8 2012 13 5 49/gr1"/>
  <input id ="filename" name="filename" type="hidden"  value="test.csv" />
</form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Hoping someone finds it useful!!
Thanks for the inputs!

Kavita

Comment: there is a problem with the downloaded file. The file is not actually returned in my solution only the path from docroot onwards is. Sometimes it gives a character encoding error and does not download the file. "The character encoding of a framed document was not declared. The document may appear different if viewed without the document framing it." This could be due to not setting the contenttype of the files data. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 2):

Your @Produces tag is conflicting with the type you set inline. If you both make them `application/octet-stream` I'd expect better results.

Comment: <div style="position:absolute;width:20px;height:20px;background:black" id="mydiv"><iframe id="hiddenDownloader" src="http:\localhost:8080\c:abc@abc.com#26 8 2012 13 5 49/gr1/output/test.csv"></iframe></div> This is what it gave me after i user iframe.src = data and changed the @produces to app/oct.. But it still did not ask me for the save download. I also changed the  dataType: "application/octet-stream", in the ajax call

Comment: The Accepts header is only part of the puzzle. The browser reacts to the content-type of the response too.